# How do I get a value from a look up input field?

Tags: actionsupport, inputfield

I am using the apex:actionSupport control to execute some code when the apex:inputField it is associated to, has its value changed.  The apex:inputField is a look up field, so it spawns a new window to do the look up and then dutifully returns the value to the control on the page.  The onchange event of the apex:actionSupport control then fires, but in my apex handler, the object the apex:inputField is bound to, does not have the value populated.  Any ideas how I can get this value?

Here's my code:

```
<apex:inputField id="ShareInputField" value="{!Share.Value__c}"> 
  <apex:actionSupport onsubmit="alert(this.value);" event="onchange" action="{!GetTarget}" immediate="true" reRender="ShareForm"/>
</apex:inputField> 

public void GetTarget(){ system.debug('USR_MSG: ' + this.Share.Value__c); }
```

Comment: What you're describing sounds like it should work. Can you post your code?

Comment: <apex:inputField id="ShareInputField" value="{!Share.Value__c}">
 <apex:actionSupport onsubmit="alert(this.value);" event="onchange" action="{!GetTarget}"
  immediate="true" reRender="ShareForm">
 </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputField>

public void GetTarget(){
    system.debug('USR_MSG: ' + this.Share.Value__c);
}

The onsubmit javascript echos out the look up value correctly, but the value within my apex code is just null.

Comment: It was the immediate="true" attribute I had used as I had to suppress the validation of other fields in order to allow the postback. If I remove this attribute the value does make it to the bound property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is that `immediate=true` flag.  When that's set, the action method is fired before the getters and setters.  This is useful for things like cancelling, when you don't actually need to process anything.  However, it's preventing the controller from getting your values.

As you mentioned, removing this causes validation failures else where.  You'll want to use the `apex:actionregion` tag to resolve this.  With this in place, only that portion of the form is processed, so validations present elsewhere won't get run.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
  <apex:inputField id="ShareInputField" value="{!Share.Value__c}"> 
    <apex:actionSupport onsubmit="alert(this.value);" event="onchange" action="{!GetTarget}" reRender="ShareForm"/>
  </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'd implemented an apex:actionRegion to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem.
It should be:

```
public pagereference GetTarget() {  
    Your logic here...

return null; 
}
```

`Public void` does not work with actionsupport

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm afraid that makes no difference.  The binding does not appear to have transferred the value that was looked up to the public property.  I can subsequently save the item and the value is available - no problem.  It's just when the apex:actionSupport event fires that it is not populated.

Comment: Can you check with 'firebug' in Firefox (Or check it in chrome) what actually gets sent to salesforce?

Comment: @MarcelMeijer public void methods should work just fine with actionsupport tags